# Why is hexdump showing 0a at the beginning of my python output?

Tags: python, newline, hexdump

This is in my code:

```
if p1 == "something":
   f = open("output.txt", "a")
   f.write("Helloworld")
   f.close()
```

And the hexdump shows this:

Expected output:

```
00000000: 48 65 6c 6c 6f 77 6f 72  Hellowor     
00000008: 6c 64                    ld
```

Current output

```
00000000: 0a 48 65 6c 6c 6f 77 6f  .Hellowo   
00000008: 72 6c 64                 rld
```

PS: I have tried `strip`, `lstrip`, removing first character...

Comment: You opened the file in append mode, so there was probably already a character in the file. If you change the mode from "a" to "wt" you will replace the contents instead.

Comment: When I run that, Python complains about `p1` being undefined. That's not a good way to start a discussion about code behaviour. That's also why you must provide a [mcve]. As new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening your file in append mode. Open your file in write mode, using `'w'` instead of `'a'`, or check whether you did not append anything to the file beforehand, as Turun Ambartanen said.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this.

Make sure you didn't create the file before, some text editors like to append a newline (0x0a) on save.

Use `f = open("output.txt", "w")` to overwrite existing content in the file.